# How to install mlpack successfully?

Tags: software-installation, boost

Currently, I am trying to install [mlpack](http://www.mlpack.org/) to Ubuntu 12.04. 
When I executed `make install`, I got the following error.

```
[  0%] Built target mlpack_headers
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libmlpack.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.a(cmdline.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libmlpack.so.1.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I fix this error and install mlpack successfully?

Comment: There's a package in utopic... http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/mlpack-bin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I re-installed every dependency using

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-math-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-random-dev
     libboost-test-dev libxml2-dev liblapack-dev libblas-dev libarmadillo-dev
```

Inside the mlpack folder: 
execute following command

```
mkdir build
cd build 
cmake ../
makes
sudo make install
```

After that to run executables set the path using this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s).....
Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

recompile your boost with -fPIC
e.g
./bjam **cxxflags=-fPIC** --without-python  --without-graph_parallel --without-graph --without-wave  install